# get_posts output always same post

Tags: wp-query, loop, query-posts, get-posts

I'm trying to output the last (chronologically) 4 posts having the tag (slug) "pp".

```
<ul>
<?php
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'taxonomy' => 'tag', 'field' => 'slug', 'terms' => 'pp' );
$tag_posts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $tag_posts as $post ) : 
  setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</ul>
```

This snippet though output 4 entries of the same post, which is the fourth from last! How come? :)

Comment: Try to add a wp_reset_query() before get_posts.

Comment: Uhm, doesn't work anymore with that :P

Comment: Before the foreach loop do `var_dump( $tag_posts );` so you can see if they really are the same post.

Comment: The result is NULL. The permalink is correct though (it's the one that title says).

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are not passing the parameters in the correct way, taxonomy param needs to be passed under `tax_query`. Please replace the `$args` with the below:--

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'tag',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'pp'
        )
    )
);
```

For more details check the **[codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters)**

Comment: I tried but with but now output is blank
New snippet: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=kQLFeetN

Comment: oops, posts_per_page has a ' where it shouldn't.

Comment: Uhm, stil no luck

Comment: can you tell me what does `var_dump($tag_posts)` return here. Please try it before the `foreach` loop and let me know

Comment: Try the code now, there was an apostrophe after 4, Rarst has edited it. please try the above code now

Thanks @Rarst